# NavigationAdapter Using Two Icons

Tags: android

I use navigationview. I want to use two icons in navigation view. Currently, when I use .seticon, it changes 2 icons. I want to define icons in two icons separately. I want to define separate icons for navIconNew and navIcon. How can we do that?

**Navigation Adapter**

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<NavigationDataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public NavigationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavigationDataModel> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navigationrecyclerview_adapter11, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.navIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.navIconNew.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(arrayList.get(position).getColor());
        holder.navTitle.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView navIcon, navIconNew;
        TextView navTitle;
        LinearLayout rootView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
            navIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.navIcon);
            navIconNew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.navIconNew);
            navTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.navTitle);
        }
    }
```

**navigationrecyclerview_adapter11**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navIcon"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navIconNew"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.6"
        android:text="Item"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sanspro_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
 NavigationDataModel model8 = new NavigationDataModel();
            model8.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
            model8.setTitle("Mesaj At");
            model8.setIcon(R.drawable.unread);

            arrayList.add(model8);
```